# Join 3 tables using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

So I have 3 tables

```
size_sets - id, name
sizes - id, name
size_set_sizes - size_id, size_set_id
```

I want to define a relationship in `size_set` model that would retrieve all `sizes` available for that `sizeset`

Something like:

```
public function sizes()
    {
       //define relationship here
    }
```

Method `sizes` should retrieve the names from the `size` table, through `size_set_sizes` table in the `size_set` model...

My application is very dynamic and thus I needed to go with this structure. I tried the `hasManyThrough` relationship, but couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Seems like a many to many: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. You might want to clean up your 3 table definition in your question as its very confusing - use bullet points or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% use a pivot table

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

This link will give you all you need

Comment: I just did that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `belongsToMany()` relations like:

```
class Size extends Model
{
    public function sizeSets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SizeSet::class, 'size_set_sizes');
    }
}

class SizeSet extends Model
{
    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'size_set_sizes');
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$sizeSet = SizeSet::with('sizes')->find($id);
```

Then `$sizeSet->sizes` will return a collection of sizes for that size set.

Comment: Exactly what I did

Answer (score 0):

I Think I found what I was looking for The answer is a pivot-table

http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/